# Unable to change user password in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: login, password, root, passwd-file

The User Password is not changing for some reason.
In the terminal it says password updated successfully,

```
$ sudo passwd
[sudo] password for zaigham: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

But when I try to log in using the new password it doesn't work. I have changed my password 2, 3 times now but still it's the same. Is that some kind of bug?

Comment: For those with the luxury of reinstallation, this problem occurred for me when I set the autologin during my install, I guess the installation process sets some files that aren't compatible with the Account settings GUI. I re-installed and didn't choose autologin. Then I was able to toggle the automatic login in the GUI and it worked. The only caveat is that the GUI will show it as OFF when you enter, it appears to incorrectly detect the current setting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change your own passwd use just `passwd` not `sudo passwd`.

Comment: @Laphanga Also, since `sudo passwd` sets a password for `root`, which should generally be avoided in Ubuntu, I recommend [reversing that action](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account) by running `sudo passwd -dl root`.

Comment: @EliahKagan MVP